# Can I use iTunesConnect even if I don't have a phone number?

Tags: iphone, mac, developer-program, sms

I don't have any SIM card (in the past I had, and used it on iTunesConnect) and I just found that when I tried to log in, the SMS verification page popped up and forced me to enter the verification.

I deactivated the phone number so I clicked the *cannot access to it* button. Then I entered the phone number that I used to use, and then the page moved to another one describing that I must add another phone number on iPhone and Mac by going to the *Settings* - *Name* - *Password and Security* (the exact name might be different as I don't set English).

However, adding another number also forces me to get the SMS verification done...

In this case is there any way to use the iTunesConnect without the phone number?